# wp_list_categories() with count only for bottom level taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

wp_list_categories() does such a nice job of listing my custom taxonomy based on parent, and even adding the count of posts inside that taxonomy as I want.

However, I need to get rid of the permalink and the count on taxonomies that are parent taxonomies, while keeping the parent category visible only by name.

So here's what I have:

```
ULTIMATE PARENT TAXONOMY LINK (2)
   IRRELEVANT PARENT LINK (3)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (5)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (1)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (2)
   IRRELEVANT PARENT LINK (3)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (7)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (1)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (2)
```

What I need:

```
ULTIMATE PARENT TAXONOMY
   IRRELEVANT PARENT
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (5)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (1)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (2)
   IRRELEVANT PARENT
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (7)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (1)
      ACTUALLY RELEVANT CATEGORY LINK (2)
```

I could just call several wp_list_categories() for each "irrelevant parent", but I'm sure that will cause massive problems later on when the client wants to expland the categories.

Here's how I'm doing it right now, just a basic function usage:

```
<?php wp_list_categories( 
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'trukkikategoriat', // my custom taxonomy
    'orderby' =>  'name'
    'show_count' => 1,
    'child_of' => 54,
    'title_li' => '',
  ) 
); ?>
```

What kind of modifications would achieving my needs require?

Comment: I could do this with javascript, loop the category structure after the loop is finished to remove the permalinks and counts from the meaningless parent categories, but that feels like the psychopath developer solution and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not to stroke my own chain or anything, but turns out answers were plentiful. My search words were simply terrible.

When I ran into the fact that you can query terms with WP_term_query it all became so simple. Full resolved answer for those who might Google the same thing with "bad" search words:

```
<?php

$cat_mastername = 'trukkikategoriat'; // The category or custom taxonomy you wish to query.

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $cat_mastername,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'child_of' => '54', // If you wish to specify a further taxonomy or taxonomies, you can do that here. Remove this if you want to query the whole taxonomy.
);

$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
$categories = $the_query->get_terms(); // single out the categories of your query result.


    if ($categories){

        foreach($categories as $category){ // loop everything and poke around.
            $ancestors = get_ancestors( $category->term_id, $cat_mastername );
            $category->ancestors = $ancestors; 
            $category->depth = count( $ancestors );
            $cat_children = get_term_children($category->term_id, $cat_mastername ); // This is the real gold. Get_term_children finds everything we need.
                if($category->depth === 1 && !empty($cat_children)) //We find the taxonomies that match our depth requirement: not the highest, but the second highest. Change the number 1 to different if you want deeper or shallower structure :?>
                    <a class="trucklist-link main-level" href="#toggle-sub-menu">
                        <?php
                            echo $category->name; // This code simply builds a blank link for the parent that is irrelevant beyond it's name.
                        ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="trucklist-sub-level">
                        <?php foreach($cat_children as $cat_child){ // Now that we found a taxonomy that matches our depth requirement, let's loop that taxonomys's children!
                            $this_cat = get_term($cat_child); ?>
                            <a class="trucklist-link sub-level" href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat_child);?>">
                            <?php
                                echo $this_cat->name;
                                echo ' ('.$this_cat->count.')';
                            ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;
            }   
        } 
    ?>
```

I hope this will help someone later!